# Difficulty debugging Magento 2 with xdebug without it calling writeClose()

Tags: php, apache, magento2, xdebug, fastcgi

As the title suggests, in some situations I step through the Magento 2 code, only for it to go to `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager::writeClose()`, thus calling `session_write_close()` and terminating the application immediately. The Call Stack is practically empty, so I can't see what is calling this. However if I insert a breakpoint and continue from there, it loads the website as if nothing has happened.

It only seems to occur on Magento 2 websites where it would suddenly terminate in such a fashion, however I'm not sure if it could be an issue with xdebug, Apache, or PHP-FPM.

Is there a reason why writeClose gets called, and how do I prevent this from occurring again whilst debugging?

### System details:

- Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (in WSL)
- PHP Version: 7.0.33
- Server API: FPM/FastCGI
- xdebug version: 2.8.1

If you require any additional information, then please leave a comment, and I shall update accordingly :-)

Comment: How does debugging session is linked to user session? The only time I believe it may be possible is when you have an error handler in Magento which gets triggered in your code, thus effectively terminating your application gracefully, calling above function in said handler.

Answer (score 0):

writeClose is called when you get an exception.

There is no way to prevent it.

The solution is to find where is the exception by debugging deeply.

When you debug then try to use F7 more instead of pressing F8 , you will go through all functionalities and get where the exception is. Then you see the root cause by exception messages.

Comment: Unfortunately this can be as simple as an "Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property" error, but if the breakpoint is set after where it causes said error, it would execute that section just fine. I haven't had this issue for a while, but I'm only just getting it again, hence why after a quick Google search I'm back here! It may be a memory issue, but if I find out the true reason, then I'll update accordingly.